# "Fresh off of" or "Fresh off" in the idiom?

Tags: idioms

If I wanted to say something like "Fresh off of the jolt after ...", would it be better written as "Fresh off the jolt after..."?

Comment: About the only expression I'm familiar with using "fresh off" is "fresh off the boat".

Comment: Style advice: consider alternatives to *off.* Both versions too closely precede the word *after* with something that sounds too similar. Also, *off* seems to be becoming an unduly favored preposition, even usurping the role of its opposite in *based on.*

Comment: _Off of_ is used in some dialects but is not standard English.

Comment: *"Fresh off of the jolt after ..."*  Unfortunately this is meaningless, regardless of the prepositions used. Please give the complete sentence and say what you want it to mean.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: *off of* is reasonably standard American English, even if it's looked down on in the U.K. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+of%3Aeng_us_2019%2C+off+of%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20of%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20of%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor, with all due respect, Ngrams can be regarded as dispositive of what is standard only if one is a really hardcore descriptivist.

Comment: In particular, NGrams don't indicate if something is acceptable in some registers/contexts/forms of writing, but not in others. "off of" may appear frequently in fiction, especially in reported speech, and in informal writing, but I'd guess it is far less common in formal prose.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, there's really [only one thing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fresh%20off%20the%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfresh%20off%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20boat%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20press%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20plane%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20land%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20trees%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20assembly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20vine%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cfresh%20off%20the%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20boat%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20press%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20plane%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20land%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20trees%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20assembly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfresh%20off%20the%20vine%3B%2Cc0) you can be ***fresh off...***

[image]

I've no idea what OP's "jolt" context is all about, but I'm sure it's essentially the ***straight after*** sense, not the ***really new, having just immigrated to a new country, or been delivered direct from an importing sea-port*** sense of the (often, more or less *metaphoric*) idiomatic ***boat*** version.

---

EDIT: Because of the lamentable tendency to associate racial variation with "evolutionary progress", expressions like *fresh off the [banana] boat* and [*straight out of the trees*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22straight%20out%20of%20the%20trees%20callers%22) are best avoided. But there is the perfectly natural and non-offensive usage...

> *[fresh **from**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fresh%20from%20the%20shock%22) [some significant **immediately-preceding** situation or experience]*

...where I've illustrated the usage with examples featuring ***shock*** because OP's ***jolt*** is relatively uncommon (but not "invalid"). For reasons that aren't clear to me, the relevant ***shock, jolt,*** or whatever is normally preceded by the *definite* article *(**the**)*, even though it probably hasn't been previously mentioned in the current narrative / conversation.

Comment: I think "fresh off the boat" owes its frequency to its usage to  mean (of immigrants) unassimilated and/or naive.

Comment: ***Fresh  off the boat:*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresh_off_the_boat

Comment: Too prescriptive. You're allowed to use less usual expressions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No you're not, Edwin. :P

Comment: The question, at its core, seemed to be about using *of* after *off*; this answer does not really address that.

Comment: "fresh off" is definitely less common: "fresh from" or "fresh out of" are more usual in expressions where you've just done something, although this source says "fresh from" is more general and "fresh out of" is American. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fresh-from-something (NB "fresh out of something" can also mean you've just run out of something.)